# I am Indian citizen, moving to germany with highly skilled visa / work permit. I want my kids to study in Holland is that possible?

Tags: germany

I am Indian citizen, moving to Germany with highly skilled visa / work permit. I want my kids (accompanied by wife) to study in Holland, is that possible?

Comment: Are you in a border town or would your family not live with you?

Answer (score 2):

Your wife and kids will need a visa/residence permit to reside in the Netherlands and they won't be able to get a dependent/family member permit if you are yourself a resident of Germany. German long-stay visas do open the right to visit other European (Schengen) countries but they are not valid for longer stays in the Netherlands.

It does not mean that it's impossible for your kids to study in the Netherlands but you will have to look at the requirements to get a Dutch visa. I don't know the details but like most countries, the Netherlands offer students' visas. You haven't specified your kids' age and what type of schooling/studies you would be looking at but I assume it's also possible to get such a visa for a secondary school.

Your wife's situation is more difficult. She won't be able to stay as a student but you cannot sponsor her as your dependent so she will need to reside in the Netherlands under some sort of long-term visitor/non-worker status. Once again, I don't know the details but even that ought to be possible. But that's usually quite difficult (e.g. it requires significant wealth). Alternatively, there might be some “caretaker” status (your kids would sponsor their mother, as it were) but that would only work if your kids already have the right to reside in the Netherlands (very often such permits are intended for non-citizen parents of citizens).

You certainly cannot do that easily based on your situation in Germany and might even need to hire a Dutch lawyer to navigate the process.

Comment: I think you mean "...but they are not valid for longer stays in the Netherlands."